# Comparing two objects in anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am building a model with anylogic. Here is the code:

```
victim = null;
for (People p : main.people){

    //když je dostatečně daleko
    if((distanceTo(p, METER)) < fightDistance){
            if( randomTrue( fightProbability ) && !p.equals(victim) ) { 
            victim = p; //set the victim
            break; //stop scan
            }
    }
}
```

The fighter is supposed to choose his victim with the probability of 20%. Two fighters can't share the same victim, which is not working. I need to make sure that the choosen people is not the victim already, though `&& !p.equals(victim)` doesn't help...

Comment: Have you overridden the equals(Object o) and hashCode methods in your `People` class?

Comment: `p.equals(victim)` will always return `false` since `victim` is null. You should use another approach. E.g. create a collection of victims and add some peopel to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals() method of People class. Inside equals() compare a unique field of People.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by creating a variable `isChased` in People class which is set as `false`. Then I implemented this into the chasing method of `Fighter` class:

```
victim = null;
for (People p : main.people){

    //když je dostatečně daleko
    if((distanceTo(p, METER)) < fightDistance){
            if( randomTrue( fightProbability ) && p.isChased != true ) { //random decision
            victim = p; //set the victim
            p.isChased = true;
            break; //stop scan
            }
    }
}`
```